# Why does this hadith say that wearing perfume is allowed while in Ihram state?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, hajj, perfume

It's stated in Saheeh Muslim ([source](http://sunnah.com/muslim/15/48)) that

> 'A'isha (Allah be pleased with her) reported that when the Messenger
>   of Allah (ﷺ) intended to enter upon the state of Ihram he perfumed
>   himself with the best of perfumes which he could find and after that I
>   saw the glistening of oil on his head and beard.

But I have heard that wearing perfume is not allowed if someone was in ihram state. What's the case here ?

Comment: Can you provide a source for the statement that wearing perfume isn't allowed in an ihram state?

Answer (score 1):

Even when you accept the prohibition of perfuming, then it's only said to be impermissible when one is **in ihram** and not outside of *ihram*.

So before entering *ihram* you put on perfume, it's fine.  That's what all the narrations say even the one you quoted =

> when the Messenger of Allah **intended to enter upon the state of
>   Ihram** he perfumed himself with the best of perfumes

He was not **in** the state of *ihram*.

waAllaho alim

Comment: I think you will confuse many people with your statement,  "First, keep in mind this report along with several others are sayings of Aisha and not the Prophet himself. Therefore, it cannot be taken as revelation from Allah."

Comment: Not only it is irrelevant to the question. it might do more harm than good. I know what you want to say. But in its current form. there will this one guy who would totally misunderstand what you said....